# Google cloud storage : get upload link (JAVA)

Tags: java, url, google-cloud-storage, bucket

I can create Bucket in my cloub but I can not find how to retrieve the url to send files in this bucket.

I can find my bucket with its name :

```
try {
            getBucket = storage.buckets().get("bucketName");
            Bucket bucket = getBucket.execute();
        System.out.println(bucket.getDefaultObjectAcl());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But getDefaultObjectAcl and getAcl send me null.

How to retrieve this url?
Thx.

Comment: Can you post bit more of the code? I mean the code were you define other variables that you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to upload a file without Token.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload#resumable

First you must use Token and file's info you want to upload to create the
resumable upload link.

Send this to google.

```
POST /upload/storage/v1/b/myBucket/o?uploadType=resumable HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Authorization: Bearer your_auth_token
Content-Length: 38
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
X-Upload-Content-Type: image/jpeg
X-Upload-Content-Length: 2000000
{
  "name": "myObject"
}
```

In the response header there is a link to use to upload a file
to Google Cloud storage.

```
Location: https://example.storage.googleapis.com/music.mp3?upload_id=tvA0ExBntDa...gAAEnB2Uowrot
```

Comment: How did you manage to get the `Bearer` token, to be used in `Authorization`?